# How can I disable(don't scroll) on left and right trackpad's movements. (jQuery scrollbars)

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, touchpad, trackpad, slimscroll

I'm using [`slimScroll`](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll?page=5)

Here is an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/rgmrw/11/

How can I disable left and right touchpad's movements. For example, by dragging two fingers UP - it scrolls UP. It's ok, the same stuff if I drag to fingers left.  Can I disable left and right movements? I just need up & down:) Maybe someone knows how to disable it or how to track it(touchpad's movements) down?  I have tried other jQuery scrollbars & I get the same behaviour.

Any help will be really appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change to [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) & everything ok:)
[example](http://www.xiper.net/examples/js-plugins/ui/jscrollpane/jquery-scroll.html)